# Eeeek! The chat logo forgot its Wheaties!

Tags: feature-request, chat

The logo on the page of [Music.SE's chat rooms](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=music.stackexchange.com) has shrunk.

[image]

It's obviously forgotten its Wheaties and is practically unreadable (give or take a little). If we could just find those Wheaties...

```
<div id="hlogo">
<div id="header-logo">
<a href="http://music.stackexchange.com" title="Musical Practice &amp; Performance">
<img style="max-width:150px" src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/music/img/logo.png?v=abcdef" alt="Musical Practice &amp; Performance">
</a>
</div>
</div>
```

`max-width` should be set larger (the original is 537 px wide).

Another option is to shorten the name (in the chat logo) to "Music". Other sites, such as [GFH](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) (shortened to "Genealogy"), have their names shortened in chat.